# Customize Gnome Shell to have icons in "Window Picker"

Tags: gnome-shell

I'm using Gnome Shell on my laptop under Ubuntu 18.04.

I love the "Window picker" menu in Gnome. Which is displayed thought the <strike>Windows</strike> Linux key that make you able to choose the app you like to display or launch.

Unfortunately, I work with lot different of IDE (Atom, Intellij, Pycharm..) all in dark mode. In order to make the difference between each other. I'm looking for a solution to display the Icon like the alt+tab shortcut does.

I have looked at the internet and haven't found a solution. Is anybody have something to propose for me ?

Comment: It seems to be exactly want I want !

Comment: You should make an answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a gnome extension adding exactly what you describe:

**[WindowOverlay Icons](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/302/windowoverlay-icons/)**